# How can I automatically print in Excel using information from another sheet?

Tags: excel, automation

I need help with a project in Excel. I have a sheet with a list of people, each of them with a numeric identifier (ID). I have another sheet in which you can use the ID to display information about that person. Is there a way to read the ID of each of the people on the list and print the information sheet for everyone without having to manually set the ID every time?

e.g.

Sheet 1:

| employee | ID |
| --- | --- |
| name 1 | id 1 |
| name 2 | id 2 |

Sheet 2:

```
Employee ID = id 1
name 1
working hours
sector
```

I don´t have much knowledge of Excel so I´m not sure if it's even possible

Comment: Yes it is possible with XLOOKUP, FILTER, VLOOKUP (if you change ID to be on left side in Sheet 1), but only to show name, because there are no working hours nor sector in your sample dataset.